# Babel with Gulp - How to set javascript file transpile order

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

In short I have an angular app and I want to use babel with gulp to transpile my .js files. However in the dist bundle.js it transpiles the controllers first and the module initiation afterwards. So I want babel to transpile .module.js files first and then .controller.js files. This way my code will be ordered correctly and controllers could be attached properly to modules. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('public/src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));
});
```

Comment: is this really necessary? anyway, why not move the modules and controllers each in their own subfolders, and gulp.src each folder in order?

Comment: Long story short, it is necessary in my case. I tried to chain .src().src() but it doesn't let me. How can I do it? @robertotomás

Comment: `.src(['foo/', 'bar/']) ` I believe

Comment: @robertotomás this solved my question. If you want post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not move the modules and controllers each in their own subfolders, and gulp.src each folder in order?

Use `.src(['foo/', 'bar/'])` to specify the order

Comment: I decided not to separate folders into MVC structure since I folder by feature. Here is how I did it: 
return gulp.src(['public/src/**/*.module.js', 'public/src/**/*.controller.js'])